# Gradient background not stretching to cover top to bottom

Tags: css, background, gradient

I am trying to implement a gradient color background. Here is the concerned code.

```css
#grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
}
```

```html
<body id="grad">...</body>
```

However, this only covers the background till my navbar, and then the background repeats itself. I tried the following code:

```css
#grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body id='grad'>...</body>
```

and the background just disappears. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want it to repeat just add no-repeat to the end of the linear-gradient.

For example:

```
background: linear-gradient(red, white, blue) no-repeat;
```

Then set your height as anything you want.

If you want to make it height = 100% then just make a div tag with the following css.

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, white, blue) no-repeat;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, white, blue) no-repeat;
background: -o-linear-gradient(red, white, blue) no-repeat;
background: linear-gradient(red, white, blue) no-repeat;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width:100%;
left:0;
top:0;
```

You don't want to make the body an absolute. But then again you wouldn't need no-repeat if you were to do it the second way with the div tag.

Comment: I tried adding no-repeat, but the background still stops till navbar. I tried adding height: 100%, but there was no change.

Comment: Try again but with a Div tag. Do not use 'position:absolute' on the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `body` will only have the height of the content and even if you set the height to 100% the browser has to know 100% of **what**.

In this case, it will be the parent `html` element which needs to have a height of 100% set.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
  background: linear-gradient(red, white, blue);
}
```

```html
<body id="grad"></body>
```